# Lotus Notes VBA Email Automation - db.CreateDocument Command Fail

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes, lotus

I'm trying to automate the sending of an email through Lotus Notes 9.0 using VBA. The code will load up notes, which asks for my password but before the password prompt shows up, I get an error. The error I run in to is "Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)': Automation Error The server threw an exception" When I hit debug, the line that it fails on is "Set obDoc = obDB.CreateDocument". A lot of what I've seen online example wise matches what I'm doing in my code, so I'm not sure where the problem is.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Send_Emails()
Dim stSubject As Variant
Dim emailList As Variant
Dim obSess As Object
Dim obDB As Object
Dim obDoc As Object

'----Create Email List - separate function, dynamically creates email list based off report processing done in other functions
CreateEmailList

'----Info for Subject
stSubject = "test subject"

'----Create Notes Session
Set obSess = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set obDB = obSess.GETDATABASE("", "")
If obDB.IsOpen = False Then
   Call obDB.OPENMAIL
End If

'----Create the e-mail - **FAILURE OCCURS HERE** 
Set obDoc = obDB.CreateDocument

'----Add values to the email
With obDoc
  .form = "Memo"
  .SendTo = "test@test.com"
  .blindcopyTo = emailList
  .Subject = stSubject
  .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><p>test</p></BODY></HTML>"
  .SaveMessageOnSend = True
  .PostedDate = Now()
  .Send 0, emailList
End With

'----Clean Up
Set obDoc = Nothing
Set obDB = Nothing
Set obSess = Nothing

MsgBox "The e-mail has been sent successfully", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you are using Notes 9, so I looked at the online help for Notes 9.01 and the [help page for the OpenMail method](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OPENMAIL_METHOD.html) says

> Note: This method is supported in LotusScript® only. For COM, use OpenMailDatabase in NotesDbDirectory.

Now, you're actually using the OLE automation classes (rooted at Notes.NotesSession), not the COM classes (rooted at Lotus.NotesSession), so I don't know if you can use the NotesDbDirectory class or not, but the other way of opening the current user's mail database would be to call NotesSession.GetEnvironmentString("MailServer",true) and  NotesSession.GetEnvironmentString("MailFile",true), and use those as the values for your call to GetDatabase.